# Why doesn't `scroll-margin` work? [Solved]

Tags: scrolling

- `scroll-margin` is `1` but Emacs still sometimes allows the *cursor* to stay at the 1st line of a *window*.

Follow these steps to reproduce it (or see the GIF below):

1. `emacs -Q`
2. In buffer `*scratch*`, `C-x C-e`:

   ```lisp
   (progn
     (custom-set-variables
      '(custom-enabled-themes '(modus-vivendi))
      '(global-tab-line-mode t)
      '(scroll-margin 1)
      '(scroll-conservatively 101))
     (info-emacs-manual)
     (end-of-buffer)
     (goto-line 500))
   ```
3. With the *cursor* now at the 2nd line from the top of the *window*, press `<up>`-arrow-key several times and pay attention to resulting *cursor* position.

[image]

---

This behavior is **inconsistent** with the documentation (and has caused me great trouble in practice):

`C-h v scroll-margin`:

> Its value is `1`
> Original value was `0`
>
> Number of lines of *margin* at the top and bottom of a *window*.

The correct behavior is what `next-line` does;

You can try the `<down>`-arrow-key after step 3 described above:

[image]

---

##### Q:

Why doesn't the setting of `scroll-margin` work here?

IOW, what causes `previous-line` to move the *cursor* beyond the *margin* (which is inconsistent with `next-line`'s behavior when Emacs *automatically scroll*s up)?

---

Information that may be helpful in troubleshooting:

- If either `'(custom-enabled-themes '(modus-vivendi))` or `'(global-tab-line-mode t)` is removed, the bug will disappear.

---

emacs-version: 28.2

system-configuration: x86_64-w64-mingw32

emacs-version: 30.0.50

system-configuration: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

---

### Question is Solved

I reported this as [bug#63201](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2023-05/msg00004.html) and it should be [fixed](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=emacs-29&id=46392c1623bc3f9764b8c7df293a89fcd47ab0ad) now on the emacs-29 branch.

Comment: Please separate (remove) everything that should be a bug report (`M-x report-emacs-bug`), and make clear what your question is. Is this the question: *"If you remove either `'(custom-enabled-themes '(modus-vivendi))` or `'(global-tab-line-mode t)`, the bug will disappear. I don't know why."*? IOW, is your question **"Why?"**? Or is this it? *"how to get previous-line to do that stably?"*

Comment: @Drew: The question has been edited.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue on Emacs 29.0.60 . The problem occurs only in at the top section of the scrolled text. Scrolling to the bottom and then up works as expected a very long time until the given upper section of text is reached where the point jumps to the first line. Quite weird this behavior. Especially because scrolling down keeps in my test a 2 lines margin and scrolling up a 1 line margin. Without the theme there is no weird behavior. With the theme but no global-tab-line-mode scrolling down keeps two lines margin. Scrolling up is OK.

Comment: See it this way: it seems not to be a bug in Emacs ... Emacs works as expected and OK. It seems to be a problem with the *modus-vivendi* theme. So the question is: is it a bug in the theme or a feature of the theme? Have you reported a bug? Just post the link to the bug report ( find the link to the bug page searching for the bug number here: https://debbugs.gnu.org/ ).

Comment: @Claudio: “*It seems to be a problem with the modus-vivendi theme.*” --- **No**. See “*if you remove either `'(custom-enabled-themes '(modus-vivendi))` or `'(global-tab-line-mode t)`, the bug will disappear.*” And in fact that my example is only one of the cases that `scroll-margin` doesn't work.  I posted only one example here because it has already taken me much time to narrow such one example down.

Comment: @Shynur if you remove `global-tab-line-mode` the *bug* of scrolling up goes away, but the *bug* of **two** lines of distance while scrolling down will be still there. Haven't you noticed yet the problem with two lines margin at the bottom?

Comment: I have checked out the code changes in the patch and failed to understand how the fix fixes the problem and how it comes that the issue was there in first place. In other words my gut-feeling is that fixing this case may have side-effects leading to not yet detected another issues.